# Unable to connect to docker host when network changes

Tags: docker, ip, windows-10, containers, docker-machine

Here I have two cases.

My office address will be like 10.10.33.XX which will be changing every day And home ip address will be like 192.168.0.100/101/102

So I want set single static ip for both the cases on Windows 10

Please suggest a way to handle this

Thanks, Kusuma

Answer (score 0):

You could communicate with containers with the help of links. For example consider an application with Mongo and Node. You can start the mongo container with:

```
docker run --name mymongodb -d mongo
```

Start an express app with:

```
docker run --express --link mymongodb:mongo  -p 8080:3000 -d username/express
```

Here in such a system we could access containers with the alias `mongo`. I could access the mongo container from the express with:

```
const dbHost = 'mongodb://mongo/mean-docker';
```

This concept can be scaled as per your need to any number of containers. Thus you could solve the problem of changing IP.